# Redirect folder to subdomain of same name

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I use to have users go to domain.com/dashboard, but now want them to go to dashboard.domain.com. Some users are still using the old address and getting a non-working/very ugly page. Is it possible to have a redirect for the subfolder (domain.com/dashboard) to the subdomain (dashboard.domain.com) even though the folder name itself is dashboard (public_html/dashboard), or would it simply be MUCH easier to change the subfolder name to something different? Here's what I currently have in the public_html's .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dashboard/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashboard.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dashboard/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `dashboard/.htaccess` if it doesn't already exist and have this rule as first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dashboard\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://dashboard.domain.com/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I removed the dashboard references in the public_html/.htaccess file, and then put your code in the public_html/dashboard/.htaccess file, and when I go to dashboard.domain.com, it just loads the public_html/index.php page, and when I go to domain.com/dashboard, it loads but in the ugly/mis-linked way that it does now.

Comment: When you open `domain.com/dashboard/`, does it not redirect to `dashboard.domain.com` ?

Comment: Nope, it just loads the public_html/dashboard/index.php with the url as domain.com/dashboard

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.